# Can't display BLOB image in iOS application

Tags: ios, json, uiimageview, blob, nsdata

I'm trying to display a BLOB image (get from web server using Json) in my iOS app, but when I run my application I get an empty UIimageView, here is my code :

```
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]];
NSData *profileImage1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[dataURL bytes] length:[dataURL length]];
UIImage *profileImage2 = [UIImage imageWithData:profileImage1];
[profilImage setImage:profileImage2];
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try `NSLog`ing various items to see if anything is null. Could be that the `dataURL` or `profileImage1` or `profileImage2` or `encodedURL` is null.

Comment: Thank you for replying Neeku, I tried what you asked me to do and I found that `profileImage2`is null however `dataURL`, `profileImage1`and `encodedURL`are ok, what can I do to solve this ?

Comment: What's the format of the image you're fetching from that URL? Not a JPEG or PNG?

Answer (score 1):

`[UIImage imageWithData:data]` only parses known image file formats like JPEG, PNG, etc. (Full info in the [decomentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Passing blobs isn't supported by `UIImage`. You need to do some decoding to be able to use the data for the UIImage. You can use [GMTBase.64](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMBase64.h?r=24) for encoding and decoding of data. Read the docs and other posts and you'll find out how to change your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you give me the link of a tutorial or a good document to guide me please ?

Comment: I gave you the link to `GMTBase.64`. If you need anything more than that, google it yourself and read different posts and articles. There are so many out there. 
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=a9KZU9PJG6zX7AaU-4DwBw#q=convert+json+blob+to+uiimage

Comment: Also, please don't forget to *accept* and up-vote the answer if that was helpful. You accept answers by pressing that check mark on the left of the answer so that it turns green.